# Colocar caminho de diretório numa variável php

Tags: php

Eu tenho o seguinte código

```
<?PHP
$directory = "placas";
//Get each file and add its details to two arrays
$results = array();
$handler = opendir($directory);
while ($file = readdir($handler)) {
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != "robots.txt" && $file != ".htaccess"){
        $currentModified = filectime($directory."/".$file);
        $file_names[] = $file;
        $file_dates[] = $currentModified;
    }
}
closedir($handler);
if(substr($file_dates[0],0, -2)==substr(time(),0, -2)){
    echo "confere no BD se existe a placa ". $file_names[0];

}
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2;url=identificar_placa.php'>";
?>
```

a variável "directory" está contendo a pasta "placas", porém,quero modificar para um diretório que está em outro caminho, mais especificamente em "C:\xampp\htdocs\placas", eu tentei colocar $directory = "C:\xampp\htdocs\placas"; e não funcionou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trate a barra do link, desta forma:

```
$directory = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/placas';
$barras = array("/", "\\");
$directory = str_replace($barras, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $directory);
echo $directory;
```

A variável *DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR* é global do php ela pega o "separador de diretório" do sistema, pode ser que o sistema utilize barra ou contra barra, então coloquei as duas no array barras para tratar qualquer tipo de url.

E se depois disso a url não funcionar, verifique se o caminho esta correto:

```
if (file_exists($directory)) {
    echo "O pasta $directory existe";
} else {
    echo "O pasta $directory não existe";
}
```

Mais uma coisa, substitua:

```
$currentModified = filectime($directory."/".$file);
```

por

```
$currentModified = filectime($directory.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file);
```

E em qualquer lugar que for utilizar barras para separar diretório.

Comment: Não funcionou. O if pra testar se o diretório existe funciona com qualquer outro diretório que eu coloque, exceto a pasta placas dentro do xamp/htdocs. Será que é por ser dentro do XAMP ou algo do gênero?

Comment: Quando você fala que não funciona é porque apresentou a mensagem "O pasta $directory não existe", ou é porque deu erro?

Comment: Porque apareceu a mensagem que o diretório não existe...

Comment: O pasta C: mpp\htdocs\placas não existe

Comment: Tente colocar a url desta forma: "C:/xampp/htdocs/placas"

Comment: Era isso... Engraçado que eu estava copiando o endereço... Valeu!

Comment: É complicado utilizar esta barra \ porque ela é usada para algumas coisas como \n quebra de linha ou \t tab, é possível que \x faça alguma coisa também, ai veio o problema.

Comment: Fiz alguns teste aqui também, com aspas simples também funciona 'C:\xampp\htdocs\placas'

Comment: php é doido demais kkkkkkkkkk o programa estava funcionando antes de eu mudar o diretório, mudei, testei, funcionou. Agora não tá dando certo mais, nem com o código original.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67333/discussion-between-wictor-chaves-and-deyci).

Answer (score -3):

Sei lá, mas posta o erro e, de repente tente usar o scandir, acho que ele é mais performático e tals como o no exemplo:

```
$directory = '/path/to/my/directory';
$excluded = ['.', '..', 'nome_do_arquivo_ou_pasta'];
$scanned_directory = array_diff(scandir($directory), $excluded);
```

Ref.: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.scandir.php